# Is the monk's Tongue of the Sun and Moon feature an active effect or a passive effect?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, monk

The Monk's [Tongue of the Sun and Moon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#TongueoftheSunandMoon-240) feature states:

> Starting at 13th level, you learn to **touch the ki of other minds** so that you understand all spoken languages. Moreover, any creature that can understand a language can understand what you say.

"Touching the ki" clearly does not require the Monk to physically touch a target. Is "touching the ki of other minds" something the monk does or is it more of a state of being and they are constantly touching all minds? Is "touching the ki" an active, conscious action, or a passive effect that happens all the time?

Comment: Related: [Can a Monk “turn off” the Tongue of the Sun and Moon feature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/170241/60913)

Comment: What's the difference? Could you describe a problem when it matters?

Comment: @enkryptor Yes, say you want to talk to a party member when hostile enemies are around, can you choose which ki's you touch?

Comment: @enkryptor Unfortunately that question assumes the answer to this one, so it's not a duplicate. Answering this one will help to answer that one though.

Comment: @NautArch that question doesn't answer this one, although this question would aid in answering that one. Neither question is a duplicate of either though.

Comment: "can you choose which ki's you touch" — this is completely different thing. The feature can be either "passive" or "active" but give no capability of choosing specific targets. It this was your actual question, you should ask this explicitly.

Comment: "that question assumes the answer to this one, so it's not a duplicate" — It *is* a duplicate in its current state. That question cannot assume this one, because that one was earlier. If your question assumed something, it was not an obvious thing, you should edit the question and say this explicitly.

Comment: @enkryptor I don't think it's worth asking "if TotSaM is active, can you choose who to target", there is absolutely no one saying that it is an active feature but hits everyone in range. The answer to the other question hinges on the answer to this one. The two questions are not asking the same thing, nor are their answers the same. They are related, that's all. This question does not assume anything.

Comment: @gszavae it's your choice. I'm just trying to explain why the question was downvoted and closed as a dup.

Answer (score 5):

## There is strong evidence that it is an active capability

First, this is strongly suggested by answers to this question: [Can a Monk "turn off" the Tongue of the Sun and Moon feature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/170241/can-a-monk-turn-off-the-tongue-of-the-sun-and-moon-feature)

You are right that *touch* in this case seems to be an active verb. And even if the RAW of the Tongue of the Sun and Moon feature is not entirely clear, the RAI is very clear. The monk's description (paragraph about Ki) says:

> As they gain experience, their martial training and their mastery of ki gives them more power over their bodies and the bodies of their foes.

The word *power* in this case is a synonym for *control*, which is confirmed by a synonym search:
https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/have_power_over.html

In conclusion, the description suggests that the monk is all about control over body and mind which is very contrary to the notion that the monk's mind is all over the place. Rather it suggests that the monk can actively touch people's minds in a controlled way for communication purposes. Much like the mages in Christopher Paolini's *Eragon*.

Answer (score 2):

## It is an active effect because it's an explicitly ki linked ability.

Nothing in D&D 5th edition can be read in isolation, everything has a context. By narrowly trying to interpret a section of text, without considering that context, we can follow an incorrect path of logic.

The Monk class is all about *mastery* of ki (***emphasis mine***):

> ***Whatever their discipline, monks are united in their ability to magically harness the energy that flows in their bodies.*** Whether channeled as a striking display of combat prowess or a subtler focus of defensive ability and speed, this energy infuses all that a monk does.
>
> [...]
>
> Monks make careful study of a magical energy that most monastic traditions call ki. This energy is an element of the magic that suffuses the multiverse—specifically, the element that flows through living bodies. Monks harness this power within themselves to create magical effects and exceed their bodies’ physical capabilities, and some of their special attacks can hinder the flow of ki in their opponents. Using this energy, monks channel uncanny speed and strength into their unarmed strikes. ***As they gain experience, their martial training and their mastery of ki gives them more power over their bodies and the bodies of their foes.***
>
> [...]
>
> As a result of the structured life of a monastic community and ***the discipline required to harness ki***, monks are almost always lawful in alignment.

The Tounge of the Sun and Moon ability states (***emphasis mine***):

> Starting at 13th level, ***you learn to touch the ki of other minds*** so that you understand all spoken languages. Moreover, any creature that can understand a language can understand what you say.

The ability to both understand all spoken languages, and having any creature understand what you speak is specifically linked to your *learned* ability to touch the ki of other minds.

In fact, from the text of the ability, it's clear that this isn't some latent ability of your body that you have awakened, but an ability triggered by you actively touching the ki of other minds that you have learned to control.

Remember:

> [Monks] as they gain experience, their martial training and their mastery of ki gives them more power over their bodies and the bodies of their foes.

As a monk, your whole class and features are defined by your mastery over ki, as a result of *careful study [of ki]*, and your incredibly disciplined approach to that study, and your life. If you cannot control whether or not you are touching the ki of another mind to facilitate them understanding you, then you can't really be described as a *master* of ki now can you?

As a result, we must conclude that you, as a monk, have the ability to choose whether or not this ability is active.